# Snowflake Task Functionality

Tags: task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Wanted to know if snowflake tasks allow you to execute a copy command from an external staged S3 bucket
into a destination snowflake table as below.

```
COPY INTO snowflaketable FROM @externalstage/tablename/ FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = CSV);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run pretty much any SQL query using a task. with a task like below, you can run that copy into statement once every hour

See [CREATE TASK](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html) documentation for more notes on syntax and options.

```
create or replace task my_copy_task
  warehouse = mywh
  schedule = '60 minute'
as
  COPY INTO snowflaketable FROM @externalstage/tablename/ FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = CSV);
```

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your reply. What would I put in the "schedule" if I want the task to run every Monday at 8 am EST?

Comment: instead of `60 minute'`  you can use `'USING CHRON 0 8 * * MON EST'` (or similar, I didn't test this just now)

Answer (score 0):

Please look into using a `PIPE` as well.  It supports the `COPY INTO <table>` command.

You don't need a warehouse for pipes and the credit usage is less than for eg. tasks.

The major drawback with pipes is that they are asynchronous, so you can't eg. postprocess immediately after import.

A pro with pipes is that they can subscribe to eg. AWS S3 create object events.